# Is there a standard metadata key in S3 for storing MD5SUM of a large object?

Tags: amazon-s3

S3 supports returning MD5SUMs for most objects in the `ETag` header.  However for objects which have been uploaded in chunks the `ETag` is no longer the MD5SUM - it can still be used for checking integrity but I really need the MD5SUM.

I'd like to store the MD5SUM in the object metadata so I can retrieve it easily on large objects.  However before I make up a key for this - is there a standard one in use by other software?

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard that I've been able to identify, and frankly, too much of the software that has been written for S3 is not very well done -- S3 provides mechanisms like the `Content-MD5` upload header that ensures S3 will flatly reject an upload corrupted in transit... which some developers don't seem to bother with -- so precedent might not be worth following, in any event.

But I've struggled with this same issue on multiple levels.

Note, though, that it is possible to calculate the S3 multipart etag of an S3 upload from a local file, if you know the part size used during the upload (which, again, screams out for a standard header for saving this information, which is otherwise lost if you don't preserve it or use a standard value).  You take the md5 if each part, in binary (not hex), concatenate them, take the md5 of that (in hex this time) plus `-` plus the number of parts, and voilá, you have the multipart etag.

My (unreleased, internal-use) tool comically named "pedantic uploader" uses x-amz-meta-content-md5hex to store the hex-encoded md5 of the entire file, as well as x-amz-meta-content-sha256hex to store the sha256.  I originally used x-amz-meta-content-md5 but that's potentially ambiguous since it could be base64-encoded.

If the object uses `Content-Encoding: gzip`, the attributes of the payload inside the gzip are also noted in the metadata by my code, with keys such as x-amz-meta-identity-content-md5hex, and the uncompressed byte count as x-amz-meta-identity-content-length, with "identity" referring to the unencoded payload before compression.  I store the upload part size in bytes as x-amz-meta-multipart-part-size, and since I pre-calculate what S3 should also generate for the etag, saving this as x-amz-meta-expect-etag.

Not sure if this helps.

Comment: Does the ETag not match the the file md5sum when you use  `Content-MD5`  on a large file? The docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) seem to imply you can rely on the ETag: "Additionally, you can calculate the MD5 while putting an object to Amazon S3 and compare the returned ETag to the calculated MD5 value."

Comment: To answer my own question, according to these docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html you cannot rely on the ETag value being the file md5sum. I guess my next question would be can you do a multipart upload using put object?

Comment: @htaccess yes, it does match if you use a `PUT` upload, from the link you cited, but that particular capability is limited to files <= 5GB that are uploaded with a single API operation.  For larger files and parallel uploads of smaller files, you have to use the [Multipart Upload API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html)    and perform the concatenation and hashing I described, above, because the ETag is `md5_hex(md5_binary(part1) + md5_binary(part2) + ... + md5_binary(partN)) + '-' + numparts`.

Comment: I don't know why it isn't documented how ETag actually works on multipart uploads, but how it works has not changed for years and seems unlikely that would.  I have always used this logic and it has always worked.  There's also an undocumented API call that allows you to learn the part size, later, of a multipart upload: `HEAD /object-key?partNumber=n`, if I remember correctly, behaves as if you had sent a range request, allowing you to learn the size of the parts of the original upload.

Comment: @Michael, thanks good to know the size that triggers this is <= 5GB do you have a reference for that? To answer my second question about multipart uploads: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/

Comment: Since I originally wrote this answer, I started including `x-amz-meta-expect-etag` with the multipart etag I calculated before beginning the upload, as a cross-check/validation mechanism to use later.

Comment: The console and other utilities will typically kick into multipart mode for smaller file sizes. 5 GB is the absolute max you can upload without using multipart.  [**Q: How much data can I store?**

*The total volume of data and number of objects you can store are unlimited. Individual Amazon S3 objects can range in size from a minimum of 0 bytes to a maximum of 5 terabytes. The largest object that can be uploaded in a single PUT is 5 gigabytes. For objects larger than 100 megabytes, customers should consider using the Multipart Upload capability.*](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)